# Transparency at vb.net win forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, transparency

i want to create a form that will be invisible. The only visible items would be a picture and a user control over it.
I have set the following setting for the form:
BackColor = white
BackgroundImage = none
TransparencyKey = white
FormBorderStyle = none

The picturebox has the following settings:
BackColor  = transparent
Image =myfile

User control settings:
BackColor  = transparent
BackgroundImage = none

the problem is that the user control transparency clears a part of the picturebox behind of it and displays the desktop. What should i do in order to see the picture box behind the user control and not the desktop.

i can not add the image as background image to the user control because it much bigger than the control.

thanks

Comment: are you sure that your picturebox doesn't just need invalidating?

Comment: you want to transparent the `Form` but not including the `Controls`?

Comment: Thank you for your time I found the solution. I had to set as parent to the user control the picture box.